# ng serve needs to be restarted when a new import is added to the module

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli

Everytime I add a Module to my imports, I have to restart the server with `ng serve` in order for the module to be used in the browser.

I am not sure what is causing this, is there some configuration that I need to change in order for this to get detected and update properly?

Comment: Do you seen any errors in de cli console when you add the module?

Comment: Well, logically, you need to reload the module that imports it, at the very least, right? What exactly are you expecting to happen?

Comment: @Alexander No there are no errors.

Comment: @HereticMonkey When I add a module to my imports, the cli should recompile the application and the browser should reload. However, when it reloads, the import was not added to the application. I have to `Ctrl+C` in the terminal and run `ng serve` again in order for the added module to load in the browser.